# ClamAV Antivirus on C

Tags: centos, clamav

I've installed Clam AV in my server, and I've programmed a scan for last nigth with crontab suing the following command:

`clamscan -r --bell -i / > /var/log/clamavscans.log`

The result was that I have 9 infectred files, but I still don't know which ones are infected, because  thre's not a list with the infected files

logfile content:

```
Known viruses: 6347590

Engine version: 0.99.2

Scanned directories: 109536

Scanned files: 786788

Infected files: 9

Total errors: 25651

Data Scanned: 167958.52 MB

Data read: 107806.87 MB (raito 1.56:1)

Time: 17506.769 sec (291 m 46s)
```

Comment: Post the results of the log file

Comment: Alredy edited with the content of the log.

Comment: Use -v for verbose and -l for the log file instead of redirecting the output.

Comment: `clamscan -r -i -v -l /` like this?

Comment: clamscan -r -i -v -l /var/log/clamavscans.log /